# Get image from stacked Keras input training data

Tags: python, numpy

I have stacked : a list of images (lst_imgs) then a list of corresponding labels (lst_labels) on two numpy arrays X_train and Y_train as shown below, where m is the number of images.

```
X = np.stack(lst_imgs, 0)/255.0
Y = np.reshape(np.stack(lst_labels, 0),(m,1,1))

X_train = X.reshape(m, 24, 40, 1)
Y_train = Y.reshape(m, 1, 1, 1)
```

each image have been read in grayscale mode following the code below, and contains only one channel :

```
cv2.imread("{}{}/{}".format(path,cl,img), 0)
```

How can I get then visualize from X_train the first image ? and also, have I performed the stacking and reshaping operations correctly ?

Thank you !